# How to run a stress test on Azure Table Storage table partition?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, stress-testing, nosql

I've read some MSDN articles about Azure Table Storage and some techniques/strategies on PartitionKeys selection and how that can benefit performance on scalable solutions.
One thing that had my attention were **stress tests**, something that was mentioned [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/11/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables.aspx).

But I couldn't find many examples of them.

How to perform these tests then and under which situations?

Comment: That's an ancient article you're referencing, which has outdated scalability targets. Look [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-scalability-targets/) for latest. As for stress-testing, that's up to you to implement, with code reading/writing data from/to table storage. Then drive load with whatever tool you feel comfortable using. The idea is just to make sure you've partitioned your data in such a way that you can handle your writes and queries within your app's tolerances.

Comment: Though not related to stress testing but this may also be a good read: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/.

Comment: Thanks for the article, I'll definitely read it guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stress testing is trying out a system at normal (and extreme) load(s) to figure out its limitations. The idea is to create conditions similar to the intended production system, then perform various actions which are similar to the actions that will be performed by your application, measuring their performance.

By stress testing Azure Tables, you'll be able to make sure that it'll be able to support the load generated by your application. It'll also allow you to play with different partitioning strategies and see their effect on performance.

To perform such a stress test, design a partitioning/keying strategy, then fill an Azure Table with a typical amount of data for your application. Then perform insertions, updates, queries and other actions as fast as possible and see if the performance meets your demands.

Comment: Hello, does Azure Portal provides any visual feedback/analytics based on the stress testing results? Or I am supposed to create any logging mechanism to get a hold on them? Sorry for the dumb question I'm a newbie on Azure.

Comment: @gdyrrahitis Azure does provide SOME monitoring, but if you want to monitor SPECIFIC performance metrics which are relevant to your application, you should do it yourself.